# Javascript vs. PHP -- Framework vs. Library

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, yii, frameworks

I am planning a large-scale project. I have a very large inventory/warehouse management system - web application - that is old and no longer meets my needs. I am planning to basically start from scratch. The current system is written in PHP with a few Javascript features (such as charts). The application is not using any framework and very minimal library use. It is mostly hard-coded. The data is coming from both mssql and mysql. Some of the current features and features want in the new system are: barcode scanning, inventory tracking and locating, order and shipment tracking and managing, user management, and basic statistics on things such as customers and vendors. I also want the interface to feel desktop-like, although eventually I may add functionality for tablets that would be located in the warehouse for the warehouse employees to use.

I have done a lot of research and am in need of some help. I see many options and do not know what is best. I am also sure that there are some options that I have not even considered. I want to work mostly with frameworks and libraries. Most javascript frameworks do not get along with PHP frameworks. I could use a Javascript framework with a PHP library, or a PHP framework with a Javascript library, or use one framework and do the rest by hand. As far as javascript frameworks and libraries go, I want to get a desktop-like feel. So that gives me things like extJS, DHTMLX, maybe kendoui, YUI, JQuery UI, and many more options. For PHP I think Zend and Yii are really looking good. I definitely want an MVC structure, however I do not know if I want that handled by PHP or Javascript. What seems to make the most sense? What other options are there? Any help here would be great!

Comment: This question appears to be too vague for the purposes of this site.

Comment: I think the choice of platform is based more on the cost of maintenance and upkeep rather than what will talk to what. When you say "Most javascript frameworks do not get along with PHP frameworks. " I don't know what you mean. Of course they do if you use them correctly.  PHP without a framework is unweildy and insecure so I would definitely use a framework like Zend or Codeigniter. Zend is probably more popular.  Jquery is fine for front end.  The key is to use frameworks and libraries that have large communities - otherwise you will be completely alone when you run into problem.s

Comment: Your comment that PHP and Javascript frameworks do not interact well with each other is completely wrong. Based on that wrong assumption you consider a suboptimal solution. It all spirals downwards from this point on, the project is doomed. I especially like that "start from scratch" part. One does not simply throw away working software.

Answer (score 3):

[**Zend Framework 2**](http://framework.zend.com/) with [**Dojo**](http://dojotoolkit.org/) is a proven combination. [**Mailchimp**](http://mailchimp.com/) seemingly uses this combination for example. Also Dojo seems having specific ZF2 [Zend_Dojo](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.dojo.introduction.html) modules.

For a full JavaScript MVC, you should consider [**AngularJS** by Google](http://angularjs.org/). Using such frameworks you barely bake HTML codes with PHP, using PHP should be more just an interface for the database. View management, controllers, HTML building will be done by JS. Same goes for [**EmberJS**](http://emberjs.com/).

I'd definitely start by picking a live product that is similar to what you are planning, and get know the underlying structure.

If you view the source of [**BitDeli**](https://bitdeli.com/) for example, you barely found any pre-baked HTML there, but a huge [**`app.js`**](https://bitdeli.com/static/dist/app.js?v=c63a02a5d19ed90779cd10007fc4a151) file built with varying tooklits.

A nice JS framework collection can help you at [JavaScript - The Right Way](http://jstherightway.org/#frameworks).